# `Manipulate` functions in different range

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to plot the following two functions in different color in one diagram with `Manipulate`. The first function in blue is

$y=s$ for $x \in [0,\frac{d-rk}{1-r}]$

$y=\frac{d+rx-x}{r}$ for $x \in [\frac{d-rk}{1-r},k]$

$y=\frac{d+rk-x}{r}$ for $x \in [k,s]$

and the second function in red is

$y=d+rk-rx$ for $x \in [0,\frac{d+rk-k}{r}]$

$y=\frac{d-rx}{1-r}$ for $x \in [\frac{d+rk-k}{r},k]$

$y=\frac{d-rk}{1-r}$ for $x \in [k,s]$

under the conditions of: $y \in [0,s]$, $s \in [2,4]$, $d \in [0,1]$, $k \in [d,2d]$, $r \in [1-\frac{d}{k},\frac{d}{k}]$.

My Mathematica code is the following:

```
Manipulate[Show[Plot[s, {x, 0, (d - r*k)/(1 - r)}, PlotStyle -> Blue], Plot[(d + r*x - x)/r, {x, (d - r*k)/(1 - r), k}, PlotStyle -> Blue], Plot[(d + r*k - x)/r, {x, k, s}, PlotStyle -> Blue], Plot[d + r k - r x, {x, 0, (d + r k - k)/r}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[(d - r*x)/(1 - r), {x, (d + r k - k)/r, k}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[(d - r*k)/(1 - r), {x, k, s}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {s, 2, 4}, {d, 0, 1}, {k, d, 2 d}, {r, 1 - d/k, d/k}]
```

which yields an error. Can anyone help please?

Comment: The main problem is that the initial values of $k$ and $r$ lead to divide-by-zero situations.  Using `{k, 0.1, 2}` and `{r, 0.1, 2}` will clear the error conditions.  Also, add something like `PlotRange -> { {-4, 4}, {-5, 5} }` as an option to your `Show` command.

Comment: Plot[s, {x, 0, (d - r*k)/(1 - r)}, PlotStyle -> Blue] what do you mean by this ? You are varying s as a Manipulate variable but you are plotting it inside plot. This does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define your functions using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

**EDIT:** Added hard limiters to `y1` and `y2` using [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html)

```
Manipulate[
 y1[x_] := Clip[Piecewise[{
    {s, 0 <= x < (d - r*k)/(1 - r)},
    {(d + r*x - x)/r, (d - r*k)/(1 - r) <= x < k},
    {(d + r*k - x)/r, k <= x <= s}}], {0, s}];
 y2[x_] := Clip[Piecewise[{
    {d + r*k - r*x, 0 <= x < (d + r*k - k)/r},
    {(d - r*x)/(1 - r), (d + r*k - k)/r <= x < k},
    {(d - r*k)/(1 - r), k <= x <= s}}], {0, s}];
 Plot[{y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, 0, s}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  Exclusions -> False],
 {{s, 3}, 2, 4, 0.02, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, 1}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 1.5 d}, d, Max[2 d, 0.01], Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 1 - d/k}, 1 - d/k, d/k, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you please help me once more in adding a restriction of $y1 \in [0,s]$ and $y2 \in [0,s]$ so that the diagram has both x-axis and y-axis symmetrical to each other? I added `{y1,0,s},{y2,0,s},` but it is not working. In fact, the two functions are inverse to each other, so I would like to have both functions to appear symmetrical in the diagram.

Comment: May I ask why `0.01`, `0.02`, and `Max[2 d,0.01]` are used? And what `Exclusions -> False` is doing?

Comment: The `0.01` and `0.02` are used to define the step size in the controls. You can change them to whatever you want or eliminate them. Since `k` is restricted to the interval `{d, 2d}`; when `d == 0` this would attempt and fail to define the control interval for `k` to `{0, 0}`. The `Max` is used to avoid this null interval.

Comment: `Exclusions -> False` shows the steps at the `Piecewise` boundaries (discontinuities) rather than just showing a gap. If you prefer a gap, just eliminate the option.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers, Bob! I'm so sorry but may I ask a followup question? I think I misrepresented my question. What I wanted from your original solution is to show only the first quadrant, rather than restricting $y1$ and $y2$ to $[0,s]$. (The original diagram showed the first and fourth quadrants.) I also wanted to make the diagram a square with the lengths of x-axis and y-axis the same so that the symmetry of the two functions, which are inverse to each other, is clearly visualized. Can you please help me achieve these two? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: To eliminate the hard limiters remove `Clip` functions. To see only first quadrant, specify `PlotRange -> {0, s}`. To have axes with same length, since both plot ranges will be `{0, s}` use `AspectRatio -> 1`. The documentation includes the various options for functions.

Comment: Thanks so much, Bob!